# How to fetch data from Firestore using react hook useEffect to avoid FirebaseError Quota exceeded

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am fetching/loading the data from Firestore and using react useEffect hook. data is showing but it is showing FirebaseError: Quota exceeded.

Where am i making mistake?

```
const [val,setVal] =useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
    const getData= async()=>{
      const dbVal = await getDocs(value)
      setVal(dbVal.docs.map(doc=>({...doc.data(),id:doc.id})))
    }
    getData()
  })
```

thanks

Comment: Well you should read how useEffect without `depsArray` behaves. In your case it makes data fetching from firebase, setting a state, which causing a rerender, and with that rerender this useEffect is reexecuted and is fetching data again. So you wrote something like infinite loop. Expensive one :)